# Spring Batch: SimpleJobRepository - Example not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I been trying to get the Spring Batch Hello World 3 example running from

http://jroller.com/0xcafebabe/entry/spring_batch_hello_world_3

I was missing some jars and someone helped me out and got the project working better but I still have a error..  can someone please help me out:

Here is my applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is the error I am getting on the console

```
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@48ff2413: defining beans [jobLauncher,jobRepository,transactionManager,step,itemReader,lineTokenizer,fieldSetMapper,itemWriter,lineAggregator,simpleJob]; root of factory hierarchy
Oct 27, 2011 1:59:46 PM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner start
SEVERE: Job Terminated in error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'step' defined in class path resource [itemOrientedJob.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'itemReader' while setting bean property 'itemReader'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemReader' defined in class path resource [itemOrientedJob.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'lineTokenizer' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]: Bean property 'lineTokenizer' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:190)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:254)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemReader' defined in class path resource [itemOrientedJob.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'lineTokenizer' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]: Bean property 'lineTokenizer' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'lineTokenizer' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]: Bean property 'lineTokenizer' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1052)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the API of [SimpleJobRepository](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/SimpleJobRepository.html) has changed between 1.1.2 and 1.1.3 (bad moment to introduce backward incompatible change IMHO).

The tutorial you are following uses Spring Batch 1.1.1 where the class above had a constructor with [three parameters](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/1.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/SimpleJobRepository.java#SimpleJobRepository.%3Cinit%3E%28org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JobInstanceDao%2Corg.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JobExecutionDao%2Corg.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.StepExecutionDao%29). Now it has four. The extra parameter is [`ExecutionContextDao`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/ExecutionContextDao.html).

Here is my completely untested solution:

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>  <!-- Extra constructor argument -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Never used Spring Batch, but perhaps you can use more recent tutorial (I don't recommend downgrading to 1.x)?